# EU: What are my rights when an airline is on strike?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, passenger-rights

Long story short: an airline was on strike and, with a notice of 3 days in advance, my flight was moved two days later, so I had to stay 2 days more where I was.
I already know that I'm entitled to no compensation for the lost working days (a strike is considered by EU law an "unpredictable event"), but when I went to the airline asking for reimbursement for hotel and meals' expenses, they said "hell, no".
Is it not my right to obtain a reimbursement for those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An airline has a duty of care irrespective of whether the delay or cancellation is caused by circumstances beyond the airline's control. The airline is responsible for food and accommodation still.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004):

> Even in the event of a flight cancellation on account of unforeseen
>   technical problems, air carriers are required to compensate
>   passengers.

Some [other random site](http://www.bottonline.co.uk/flight-delay-compensation/claim-guides/strike-action-effects-on-flight-compensation) specifically mentioning strikes:

> Whilst you are not able to claim monetary compensation when your plane
>   is delayed or cancelled due to strike action, under EC261/2004 the
>   airline still has a duty of care to passengers. Article 9 of the
>   Regulation sets out in more detail the care and assistance that the
>   airline must provide free of charge.
>
> If you find yourself caught up in strike chaos here are your
>   entitlements: My plane has been delayed by over two hours due to
>   industrial action
>
> - Meals and refreshments in reasonable relation to the waiting time
> - Hotel accommodation in cases where a stay of one night or more becomes necessary
> - Transport between the airport and the accommodation
> - Two telephone calls, telex or fax messages or email